# PHP OOP routing

Tags: php, oop

i want to make a very simple website but with OOP PHP. I got enough experience in programming (c#, c++, php, js and more) so i know how to make classes etc, but the thing i dont understand with php is the correct way to call things.

there are hundreds of tutorials oop php on the internet but nothing with this (or maybe its a weird question :P).
let me explain.

for example i want a news website and i got a class News with the function create.
if i follow the url mywebsite.com/news/create or mywebsite.com/news?action=create i want to execute the php class News, action create.
but how am i suppose to do this. do i need to make in index.php

> if(action == news) news->create();

and for every action another... i dont think so :P. so how can i make this correctly? or is it better to take a simple mvc framework?

Thnx,
Stefan.

Comment: I like the [Yii](http://www.yiiframework.com/) framework. You should look into it.

Comment: I already worked with Yii framework :) and its great. but is it really needed to use a whole framework when making small websites? or can i route such things myself.

Comment: It is possible! I added some precisions in my answer, along with a link, check it out!

Answer (score 2):

I would use the CodeIgniter framework for this, it is EXTREMELY easy to install, plus it uses the the MVC design pattern.

Then to make your url like this: "mywebsite.com/news/create" you can change a simple thing in the htaccess file like such:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Source:
http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html

---

If on the other hand you don't want to use a framework, you can just use Apache's mod_rewrite to remove the script filename, then using php's *explode* function to get the function and parameters from the $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] variable.

There is a good example here:
http://www.phpaddiction.com/tags/axial/url-routing-with-php-part-one/

Answer (score 0):

i know many frameworks and i worked with codeigniter, and yii. I prefer yii but the mean question for me is, is it possible to work without such frameworks and route things or is it better to take a framework.